# How to query different group of data with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have below requirement, just wondering if there is a smart way to get this with minimal number of query :

Below is my two table User and Score, I want to segregate users into 4 groups based on their salary and average score.

1. Users with salary > Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score > Median of Score(This is Constant: 5).  `[6. Rocky, 8.Vicky]`
2. User with salary > Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score < Median of Score(This is Constant: 5)   `[5.Roy, 7.Antony]`
3. User with salary =< Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score >= Median of Score(This is Constant: 5)  `[1.Jack, 2.Tony, 4.Bony]`
4. User with salary =< Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score <= Median of Score(This is Constant: 5)   `[3.Sham]`

## User

```
Name    user_id   salary
Jack     1       100
Tony     2       200
Sham     3       300
Bony     4       400
Roy      5       500
Rocky    6       600
Antony   7       700
Vicky    8       800
```

## Score

```
id     score    user_id
1        4        1
2        8        1
3        9        1
4        2        2
5        10       2
6        3        3
7        6        4
8        7        4
9        2        5
10       4        5
11       9        6
12       1        7
13       5        8
14       9        8
15       2        8
16      10        8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions to calculate the median values in subqueries.  The rest is just aggregation and conditional logic:

```
select p.user_id, p.salary, avg(s.score) as avg_score,
       (case when p.salary <= p.median_salary and
                  avg(s.score) <= s.median_score
             then 'low-low'
             when p.salary <= p.median_salary and
                  avg(s.score) > s.median_score
             then 'low-high'
             when p.salary > p.median_salary and
                  avg(s.score) <= s.median_score
             then 'high-low'
             when p.salary > p.median_salary and
                  avg(s.score) <= s.median_score
             then 'high-high'
        end) as grouping             
from (select u.*,
             percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by salary) over () as median_salary
      from users u
     ) u join
     (select s.*,
             percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by score) over () as median_score
      from score s
     ) s
     on p.user_id = s.user_id
group by p.user_id, p.salary, p.median_salary
```

Comment: Thanks!! 
 But I also wants to pull records with a limit. For example I have thousands of records and I wants to pull first 10 record for each group order by salary.

Comment: @SekharDutta . . . That is not the question that you asked and this answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, ask it as a *new* question.

Comment: Please Check my new question on below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59578100/how-to-query-different-group-of-data-with-sql-with-limit