# How to query different group of data with SQL with Limit

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have below requirement, just wondering if there is a smart way to get this with minimal number of query :

**Below is my two table User and Score, I want to segregate users into 4 groups based on their salary and average score. I should be able to query data with limit. For example I could have millions of user so that I would like to query only top 10 for each group order by salary.**

Users with salary > Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score > Median of Score(This is Constant: 5). `[6. Rocky, 8.Vicky]`
User with salary > Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score < Median of Score(This is Constant: 5) `[5.Roy, 7.Antony]`
User with salary =< Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score >= Median of Score(This is Constant: 5) `[1.Jack, 2.Tony, 4.Bony]`
User with salary =< Median of Salary (Based on below data it is 400) and average score <= Median of Score(This is Constant: 5) `[3.Sham]`

## User

```
Name    user_id   salary
Jack     1       100
Tony     2       200
Sham     3       300
Bony     4       400
Roy      5       500
Rocky    6       600
Antony   7       700
Vicky    8       800
```

## Score

```
id     score    user_id
1        4        1
2        8        1
3        9        1
4        2        2
5        10       2
6        3        3
7        6        4
8        7        4
9        2        5
10       4        5
11       9        6
12       1        7
13       5        8
14       9        8
15       2        8
16      10        8
```

Comment: How do you define "top 10"?

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tweak on the answer in your previous question:

```
select u.*
from (select p.user_id, p.salary, avg(s.score) as avg_score,
             row_number() over (partition by p.salary <= p.median_salary, avg(s.score) <= s.median_score order by rand()) as seqnum
      from (select u.*,
                   percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by salary) over () as median_salary
            from users u
           ) u join
           (select s.*,
                   percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by score) over () as median_score
            from score s
           ) s
           on p.user_id = s.user_id
      group by p.user_id, p.salary, p.median_salary
     ) u
where seqnum <= 10;
```